# How to stop only one user, say with id=22 from from create/update methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, controller

I am using devise and have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

on a resource PAGE, now the pages can be created/updated by any registered user but I don't want a specific user, say with :id = 22 to not have thls. How to do this ?

for example this is my update code on PageController

```
@page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

so I want to make it like

```
if user.id != 22
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: For the current signed-in user, helper is current_user and try current_user.id != 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it in your pages controller by

```
if current_user and current_user.id != 22
  ...
```

Or by `before_filter` in your pages controller by

```
before_filter :check_for_specific_user, :only => [:create, :update]

def check_for_specific_user
  if current_user and current_user.id == 22
    # redirect or something
  end
end
```

Or you may do it in your application controller by

```
before_filter :check_for_specific_user

def check_for_specific_user
  if params[:controller] == 'pages' and ['create', 'update'].include? params[:action] and current_user and current_user.id == 22
    # redirect or something
  end
end
```

Also probably it is a good idea to have a method in application controller like

```
def admin?
  current_user and current_user.id == 22
end
```

Then in pages controller you will be able to write just

```
if admin?
  # ...
end
```